# How to display a fragment in Main Activity based on whether the list is empty or not?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am developing an Android app for upcoming birthday. I have a method which checks the dates in SQLite database if there is an upcoming birthday in two days and loads to list. There are also two fragments: MainFragment and BirthdayFragment. When launching the app, I want BirthdayFragment to display only if the list contains something and when there is none it should display MainFragment instead. But when I launched the app using the code below it displayed an empty activity. I tried this when the list was empty and when it was not empty.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //check for upcoming birthday here...
    //if we have birthday, display Birthday Fragment
    DatabaseOperations dbo = new DatabaseOperations(getApplicationContext());
    List<Student> studentList = dbo.getAllStudentsToList();
    if (studentList.isEmpty())
        //if we don't have any birthday, display main fragment
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
            replaceFragment(fragment);
        }
    else {//if we have any birthday, display birthday fragment
        BirthdayFragment birthdayFragment = new BirthdayFragment();
        replaceFragment(birthdayFragment);
    }
}
```

However, if remove the code to check for upcoming birthday, it displays the MainFragment well. The code is:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
        replaceFragment(fragment);
    }
}
```

Below is the method to replace fragments

```
public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

I need your help please.

Comment: try not to put inside the savedInstanceState  and use getSupportFragmentManager instead of getFragmentManager

Comment: @Chata is the BirthdayFragment correctly handling sql requests on a background thread?

Comment: after removing the savedInstanceState If block, it worked fine. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Lino it is not on background thread